# Is it possible to change web form url name dynamically upon button click?

Tags: c#, forms, url, web

I am trying to see if the function even exists. I'm sure everything is possible. Here is the scenario:

I have a web based application that displays a form. After all the parameters are filled in, and the "submit" button is clicked. I would like that completed page to stay intact, but have the url change so that an employee (from another terminal) can check (by clicking a link on a "queue" page) and approve the form prior to final processing.

Is this possibly... and any ideas on how to do it in C#?

FYI... the final process is that the form (currently) imports each filled in value/signature into a PDF template and stores it as a completed PDF.

Comment: Seems like you could create the HTML of the page, including all the parameters the user entered, and save it to the server with a new name ... then redirect to that newly-created URL.

Comment: I am sure there is a way, But, one way you could explore is using a database to store the information the user inserted when they hit submit, and then, an employee would see there is something new to approve, and using the data from the database, populate something on the employee side.